# Is the complex plane homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of complex numbers homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

They are isomorphic. Are they homeomorphic?

Comment: What is required to prove the two are isomorphic? What is required to show the two are homeomorphic?

Comment: As topological spaces, they are the same space, so they are obviously homeomorphic.

Comment: @Crostul: That depends on the exact construction of $\mathbb C$ you're using. It's quite common to define it as $\mathbb R^2$ with additional field operations, but other options include the ring $\mathbb R[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle$ or the ring of real matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Crostul I find that a very vague and handwavy comment that does not help the asker of the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The topologies of both spaces are induced by the Pythagorean norm, so the bijection
$$
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\Bbb{R}^{2} & \to     & \Bbb{C} \\
(x,y)       & \mapsto & x + i y
\end{matrix}
\right\}
$$
maps open balls of $ \Bbb{R}^{2} $ to open balls of $ \Bbb{C} $ and vice-versa.

Comment: Or in other words, an isometry (i.e. an isomorphism of metric spaces) is always a homeomorphism (i.e. an isomorphism of topological spaces).

Comment: @Henning: Exactly, Mr Makholm! :)

Comment: What about the fact that the complex plane can be mapped onto the surface of a sphere, so that in particular "infinity" behaves as a single point? Whereas in the $2D$ real space there are in general differences between "+ infinity" and "- infinity" on e.g. the real axis?

Comment: @M.Wind: The set of points in $ \mathbb{C} $ that are sufficiently far away from a given compact subset of $ \mathbb{C} $ has only one connected component, whereas the set of points in $ \mathbb{R} $ that are sufficiently far away from a given compact subset of $ \mathbb{R} $ has two (and no more) connected components. This is the reason why $ \mathbb{C} $ can have only one point at infinity, whereas $ \mathbb{R} $ can have up to two points at infinity.